# Entity framework update seed data - data motion migration

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

My seed data uses the `HasData` method for insert:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<SystemResource>().HasData(new[]
{
    new SystemResource()
    {
        Id = 1,
        Code = "roi-dev-003",
        IsEnabled = true,
    }
});
```

I would like to change the value of the `Code` property of generated seed data to a new value. Can it be done using seed data or is an sql update of DB needed?

The signature of the `HasData` method says it is used to generate data motion migration. How does a data motion migration work?

Update:
Changing the value of `Code` property and then running `update-database` has no effect:

```
PM> update-database
No migrations were applied. The database is already up to date.
```

Comment: Have you already updated the database with `Code = "roi-dev-003",` value migration?

Comment: I changed the value of `Code` property in code, then called `update-database`, but the value in database has not changed.

Comment: Okay let me check in my side.

Comment: One more question. Have you changed the Code value before applying the first migration?

Comment: There is only one, the initial migration. The value of Code I changed after this initial migration.

Comment: Have your changed code value in initial migration code and the apply the initial migrations?

Comment: I have not changed the generated initial migration that I created with `add-migration init`.

Comment: As per as I am concerned you cannot update existing data with see data procedure. It only works for the insert operation now. You have to make the changes manually in database.

Comment: @TanvirArjel ok, i see, thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, it doesn't appear that this functionality is supported in EFCore currently.

This [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2018/august/data-points-deep-dive-into-ef-core-hasdata-seeding#no-migrations-ensurecreated-does-the-job) is a pretty in-depth overview of the `HasData` system. This line from it is relevant:

> But HasData isn’t a silver bullet. Keep in mind that this feature is best for seed data that will remain static once it’s been inserted into the database.

I too have been looking for a good solution to this problem